# cannot pass height to scrollview.content size

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, ios4, uiscrollview

I am expanding the text view to its size of content like below

```
CGRect _frame = descriptionText.frame;
_frame.size.height = descriptionText.contentSize.height;
descriptionText.frame = _frame;
```

and the content is exceeding the view and could not scroll down to see the text.

I tried setting the size of scroll view like this

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(295,_frame.size.height);
```

but it fails to scroll,but works if i give a numeric value like this

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(295,600);
```

I need to set the size of the scroll view to the size of content which is dynamic.
How can I do that?

**EDIT**
description text

```
CGRect descriptionTextViewRect = CGRectMake(15, 185, 280, 85);
descriptionText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:descriptionTextViewRect];
descriptionText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
descriptionText.text =offerdes;//this is the text fetched from an xml and is dynamic.
descriptionText.editable = NO;
descriptionText.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
descriptionText.clipsToBounds = YES;
descriptionText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
descriptionText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
[scrollView addSubview: descriptionText];
[descriptionText release];
```

Comment: what is the value of _frame.size.height, also try to increase the accpet rate

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith the _frame.size.height is returning null, though the view has expanded.

Comment: what is the value of "descriptionText.contentSize.height"?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith descriptionText.contentSize.height also returns null

Comment: what is descriptionText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This segment of code that changes the size, **must** be called after you add the textview to the scroll view

after this line

```
[scrollView addSubview: descriptionText];
```

You can use this segment

```
CGRect _frame = descriptionText.frame;
_frame.size.height = descriptionText.contentSize.height;
descriptionText.frame = _frame;
```

I just tested it and it works

Make sure about the following

- that you are correctly adding the textview to the scrollview
- that the offerdes is not nil

Comment: yes thank you. it is now working, i jus now added extra 350 to the height and now it is scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the way you are setting the size, but that your variable storing the frame is not set correctly.

You need to look elsewhere in your code to track down why your descriptionText.contentSize is returning CGSizeZero.